# What is the date_time format in JsStore

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

I'm using the indexedDb wrapper JsStore.  One of the data formats they list in the getting starter guide is "date_time".  What is that format?  MM/DD/YYYY? MM-DD-YYYY? MM-DD-YYTHH:MM?  I've been trying combinations but to no avail

Comment: that is date object i.e new Date()

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the format is
Day_abbr Month_abbr DD YYYY HH:MM:SS GMT_offset.

ex: Thu Apr 16 2020 20:03:08 GMT-0600
 I say apparently because I could not find this documented.  What I did was create a variable using new Data() and then inserted that into the table.  It didn't bomb.